# Using screen command with aws ec2 start-up script doesn't work

Tags: command-line, scripts, startup, minecraft, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to start up a minecraft server as soon as my ec2 instance boots (it has a CloudWatch event to stop and start the instance everyday, so when it boots i need to start the server)

My server's folder sits in `/home/ec2-user/minecraft/` and inside this folder i have a *start-server.sh* script that runs the following command:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.15.2.jar nogui
```

I can manually use `screen` to start the server in the background and it works just fine, i can exit my ssh session and the server is still running.

But when i try to use `screen` inside the start-up script the screen session doesn't start. Below are the 3 things that i've tried so far:

1. Added a *start-server-on-boot.sh* script inside `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot` with the following command:

`screen -dmS "minecraft" ~/minecraft/start-server.sh`

What i was expecting to accomplish here was to start a detached screen session with the server 
running. If i run this script manually from the `per-boot` folder it works as expected. But when it 
runs during start-up it doesn't work (when i ssh into the machine there's no screen session created)

I checked the `cloud-init.log` for more details and the script ran without errors:

`util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/start-server-on-boot.sh'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=True, capture=False)`

2. Added the script in the `/etc/rc.local` file. Also tested manually and it works, but when the instance boots it doesn't (no screen session created).
3. Added a `User Data` script into my ec2 instance with the same `screen` command and it doesn't work as well. Tested running other commands and those worked (created a `foo.txt` file)

I checked the `cloud-init.log` as well and the script ran without errors:

`util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/userdata.txt'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=True, capture=False)`

---

I believe that the issue is that the screen session is terminating for some reason.

I really don't know what else can i try here and really hope i'm making a silly mistake that someone can see and i can get this thing to work (it's the last thing missing in order to get everything up and running)

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a permission issue. AWS EC2 start-up scripts runs as root, therefore it was not able to find the `java` command neither the `minecraft` folder, because those were accessible only from the `ec2-user` (which was the one that i ssh'ed with)

So the solution was to change the command from the `start-server-on-boot.sh` script that sits inside `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot` to the following:

`runuser -l ec2-user -c 'screen -dmS "minecraft" ~/minecraft/start_server.sh'`

That way it was able to find both the `minecraft` folder and the `java` command and the screen session got created with the server up